# Kendo UI Using template data as a javascript variable

Tags: variables, kendo-ui

I am looking for a way (if there is any) to use data retrieved from the datasource, inside the template, as javascript.

Let me clarify...

In my datasource results i have a variable called `ItemType`.
In a template i would use this variable using `${ItemType}` to 'echo' it in the page.

You can use javascript inside the template by using `# if (...) { console.log('test') } #`.

What i want to achieve, is to use the `${ItemType}` *inside* the template's javascript like this:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="dossier_template">
# var type= "${ItemType} "; #
```

If i can set a variable depending on the datasource item, i can use if-statements within the rest of the template like this:

```
# if(type == '1') {#
   <div class="type_one"></div>
# else { #
   <div class="type_two"></div>
#
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
# var type= ItemType; #
```

This should also work:

```
# if(ItemType == '1') {#
   <div class="type_one"></div>
# else { #
   <div class="type_two"></div>
#
```

Comment: That was way too simple for me not to have figured this out! Thanks man!